# replacing ifstream with ofstream doesn't have an effect

Tags: c++, io

In this code:

```
//Program To Read Words Separated By White Space
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>


int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("file.txt",std::ios::in);

    std::cin.rdbuf(f.rdbuf());

    while(std::cin>>std::skipws>>s)
        std::cout<<s<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Even if `ifstream` is replaced by `ofstream` the code exhibits the same behaviour - Why is that happening? Should there be any error for using output stream object to open a file in read mode?

Comment: You don't have `ofstream` in the code.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That's why I asked that even replacing `ifstream` doesn't disturbs the output.

Comment: What are you trying to do, redirect `std::cin` to come from `file.txt`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I am reading words from `file.txt` and storing them in the string variable and then `std::skipws` skips the white spaces present in the file and reads another word.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus *I am reading words from file.txt and storing them in the string variable... skips the white spaces present* -- Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What's wrong with just `getline` and `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well the question is not about whether to use `skipws` or `getline`.

Comment: I think there is no specific reason it'd stop you from open a file in `ios::in` mode. `ofsream` would automatically append `ios::out` anyway.

Comment: and since the file is open for read, there is no reason rebind it to cin would cause problem.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting them. In this case, that means changing `std::ifstream f; f.open ("file.txt",std::ios::in);` to `std::ifstream f("file.txt",std::ios::in);`.

Comment: @PeteBecker At this point of my study I can't see any benefit to it, could you please show me how is it better?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus -- suppose the default constructor does some network lookup that takes a long time, and the other constructor doesn't. But more generally, separating meaningful initialization from creation leaves a gap, and a possibility for errors; suppose, in the course of maintenance, you delete the code that sets the value; the code is still valid, but you've got an incorrectly initialized object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the only difference between `fstream` and `ofstream` is that `ofstream` *adds* the `out` option before opening the file.
That is, your stream is open in both directions.

You could argue that this is an error, but it's not easy to fix well given the class hierarchy.

That said, you're not supposed to specify any direction at all for `ifstream` and `ofstream`, but write

```
std::ifstream f;
f.open("file.txt");
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
std::ifstream f("file.txt");
```